# Unable to reset app state between tests in same Detox test suite

Tags: react-native, jestjs, detox

I have several Detox test files/suites that are separated into test suites for various high level app features. We have Detox set up with the following behavior:

```
  detox: {
    behavior: {
      cleanup: {
        shutdownDevice: true,
      },
      init: {
        exposeGlobals: false,
        keepLockFile: false,
        reinstallApp: true,
      },
      launchApp: 'auto',
    },
  },
```

and also call `device.launchApp` with the `newInstance: true` param set. I'm seeing that between test FILES, the app state completely resets, as I'd expect, but not between tests within the same suite. This is most noticeable via our auth state: the first test in a suite will log in to the app, and I'd expect the second to need to do the same, but the app is still logged in when the second starts running.

I've tried to set up a `device.terminateApp` in an `afterEach`, and that doesn't seem to do anything. I've also tried `device.uninstallApp`, but that results in a bunch of errors I haven't tried debugging yet.

From the docs (for Detox 20), it sounds like `newInstance` is supposed to be sufficient to reset state, but it looks like it doesn't wipe storage as part of that: how would I go about *actually* resetting state (including AsyncStorage) entirely?